# TypeScript: Recursive Deep Mutable with Generics. Error: T is not assignable to Mutable<T>

Tags: typescript, generics, mutable, typescript3.0

I'm trying to write a deep recursive `Mutable` type:

```
Mutable<T> = ...
    // remove all "readonly" modifiers
    // convert all ReadonlyArray to Array
    // etc.
    // and do it all recursively

const mutate = <T>(val: T, mutateFn: (mutableVal: Mutable<T>) => void): T => {
  return null as any
}
```

It's working fine as long as I don't use generics:

```
// works fine
mutate([] as ReadonlyArray<string>, mutableVal => {
  mutableVal.splice(42, 0, "test");
});
```

But when using it within a generic function I get an error:

```
// Error: Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Mutable<T>'.
const doSomething = <T>(array: ReadonlyArray<T>, index: number, elem: T) => {
  mutate(array, mutableVal => {
                      // Here's the error
                      //         v
    mutableVal.splice(index, 0, elem);
  });
}
```

I understand, that the mutable array's type is `Array<Mutable<T>>`, and that `splice` now expects a `Mutable<T>` value, instead of `T`. But I can't figure out how to solve it.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

I've created a TypeScript Playground, so you can play with the code:
[Link to TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Mutable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20(Array%3Cinfer%20U%3E%20%7C%20ReadonlyArray%3Cinfer%20U%3E)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20MutableArray%3CU%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20object%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20%7B-readonly%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20Mutable%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20T%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MutableArray%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20ReadonlyArray%3Cinfer%20U%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20Array%3C%7B%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20Mutable%3CT%3E%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20-readonly%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20Mutable%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0Aconst%20mutate%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(val%3A%20T%2C%20mutateFn%3A%20(mutableVal%3A%20Mutable%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20T%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'T'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'Mutable%3CT%3E'.%0D%0Aconst%20doSomething%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(array%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3CT%3E%2C%20index%3A%20number%2C%20elem%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mutate(array%2C%20mutableVal%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mutableVal.splice(index%2C%200%2C%20elem)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: `T` and `Mutable<T>` are obviously not compatible, but how do you want to handle this? The simple option would be to have `elem` typed as `Mutable<T>`. The other would be not to do deep mutable on arrays ...very much depends on your use case  what you want to do

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle this, that why i created this question. `T` and `Mutable<T>` should always have the same structure: `{ readonly foo: string }` becomes `{ foo: string }`. And `ReadonlyArray<Foo>` becomes `Array<Foo>`. The usecase is just like in the code I posted: The `mutate` function. But in some cases I want to use the `mutate` function within another function (like `doSomething`) and then it won't work anymore. Of course I could just write `elem as Mutable<T>` and it works fine. But I was hoping for some solution where it works just out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to do something like this:

```
const doSomething = <T>(array: ReadonlyArray<T>, index: number, elem: T) => {
    mutate({ array: array, elem: elem }, mutableVal => {
        mutableVal.array.splice(index, 0, mutableVal.elem);
    });
}
```

The idea is that you need `elem` to be mutable in order to add it to a deep-mutable array, but your original call was not doing that.  Since you want to mutate both `array` and possibly `elem`, the most straightforward solution is to pass in an object containing both `array` and `elem`, and operate on the deep-mutable version of that.

Only you know if it's acceptable to call `mutate()` on `elem` as well as on `array`, since the implementation of `mutate()` is left out.  I'm guessing it's going to be something involving an assertion like this:

```
const mutate = <T>(val: T, mutateFn: (mutableVal: Mutable<T>) => void): T => {
    mutateFn(val as Mutable<T>); //‍♀️
    return val;
}
```

in which case I'd say "who cares" whether you call `mutate()` on `elem`, or whether you just assert `elem` to its mutable counterpart inside `doSomething()`.  On the other hand, if your implementation is something fancier involving cloning, then you should think about whether it makes sense to call it on `elem` or not.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: That's a possible solution, too. Thank you. Basically the `mutate` function should make **one** object (or array) mutable. The `elem` doesn't need to be mutable if you only want to mutate the array. If you want to mutate `elem`, you'd call `mutate(elem, ...)`. Or if you want to mutate both, you'd call `mutate` for both (, or as in your code: Make a new object, where both are inside). There are lot's of solutions to this (, you could even just use `as any` everywhere). I only though that it's maybe possible to keep it simple and let TypeScript do it's work behind the scenes.

Comment: "The `elem` doesn't need to be mutable if you only want to mutate the array."  But you can't add an immutable element to a deep-mutable array, right?  That's what makes it "deep".  If you only want to mutate an array but not require that its contents be mutable as well, then you just want a plain `Array<T>`, not an `Array<Mutable<T>>`, which is what `Mutable<ReadonlyArray<T>>` becomes.

Comment: It really sounds to me like you want something inconsistent.  Your choices are either to make a shallowly mutable version of `array` (which means you can't call `mutate()` as defined above on `array`), make a mutable version of `elem` (which means you need to call `mutate()` on *both* `array` and `elem`), or you want to just assert your way out of the situation by calling `mutate()` only on `array` and passing in `elem as Mutable<T>` instead of `elem`.  But in the last case you will have to intentionally silence the (valid) compiler message warning that you're trying to do something unsafe.

Comment: Yes that's true. I haven't thought about that case at all yet... *"What if you add an immutable `elem` to the mutable `array` and then try to mutate the elem?"* My first thought is: Mutating the `elem` is forbidden, even after adding it to the array. But everything that was inside the array before should be mutable. Maybe I need to sleep over it another night :D Anyways: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Using DeepNonNullable from utility-types as inspiration and 99% of the code I came up with this:

```
import { Mutable } from 'utility-types';

export type DeepMutable<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => any
  ? T
  : T extends any[]
  ? DeepMutableArray<T[number]>
  : T extends object
  ? DeepMutableObject<T>
  : T;
/** @private */
export type DeepMutableArray<T> = Array<DeepMutable<Mutable<T>>>;
/** @private */
export declare type DeepMutableObject<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: DeepMutable<Mutable<T[P]>>;
};
```